# Java - Jackson Annotations to handle no suitable constructor

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am using Jackson ObjectMapper to read my response. Also I am using Spring ResponseErrorHandler to handle that response:

```
@Override
public void handleError(final ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), ServiceError.class);
}
```

I know that problem can by solved by adding default constructor, but I can't do that. I can't change ServiceError class at all.

Error got is this one:

```
No suitable constructor found for type ... can not instantiate fromJSON object(need to add/enable type information?)
```

Is there are any Jackson annotations to support such issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the class in question has suitable constructor to use, you can use `@JsonCreator` to indicate that that constructor is to be used. Also, if it takes multiple arguments, you will need to add `@JsonProperty` to indicate which JSON property should be mapped to which argument.

Comment: Do you have any example how it should look like?

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to use @JsonCreator without changing the class itself, and the question says that ServiceError can not be altered?

Comment: @EssexBoy you can use mix-in annotations even if you can not modify the class itself; see f.ex http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations (section 8) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857897/how-do-correctly-use-jackson-mixin-annotation-to-instantiate-a-third-party-class (in your case, it will work since type is not one of JDK types)

Comment: Thanks, very useful

Answer (score 2):

Define a JsonDeserializer

```
public class ServiceErrorSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<ServiceError> {

    @Override
    public ServiceError deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {

        ServiceError serviceError = new ServiceError(null, null);

        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        serviceError.setName(node.get("name").asText());
        serviceError.setDescription(node.get("description").asText());

        return serviceError;

    }
}
```

Then register it with your objectMapper

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
    ServiceError serviceError = new ServiceError("Noby Stiles", "good footballer");
    serviceError.setName("Noby Stiles");
    serviceError.setDescription("good footballer");
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(serviceError);

    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addDeserializer(ServiceError.class, new ServiceErrorSerializer());
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

    ServiceError serviceError2 = objectMapper.readValue(json, ServiceError.class);
    assertNotNull(serviceError2);
    assertEquals("Noby Stiles", serviceError2.getName());
}
```