# How to know which bean was injected into interface?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-java-config, interface-implementation

So I have a set packages that are my base code for extended applications. My application implements a series of interfaces that then are inject by spring during run time (As configured). I would like to know is there is a way that I could know which class that implements the interface was injected. I need this because I have JSON serializer/deserializer actions that I would like to perform but for that I need to know the class that was injected.

I have an java config file that will describe the wiring and it will be provided with the game implementation. But so far I haven't been able to get the concrete class implementing the interface. I also haven't been successful to request that info from the context.

Ant hints?

Comment: If you can get that then the purpose of interfaces is lost, right?

Comment: @DNAj I understand your point, but otherwise I wouldn't be able to handle JSON conversion(Jackson), since I am using a POJO containing an interface that is supposed to be implemented by my app. For sure there is a design issue here, but I cannot come around  how to solve it without know the implemented class.

Comment: Hi @jfzr, then you have option of reflection only. By using reflection properly you can make changes to access modifiers also and make them accessible. Let me know if you need more information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I came around this issue was by injecting an object into the JSON deserializer and use a getClass() method as the template to Jackson to use. And it worked like a charm, even thought the implementation to be injected was injected into a wiring happening in the dependency!. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to let the injected instance tell you what implementation class it is: `injectedInstance.getClass().getName()`. However, unless you're doing something special, consider this a hack. You probably should revisit your design so that you do not need to do that.

Comment: Indeed, I think this is gonna be my partial solution while I solve this design issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply autowire an interface and get the implemented class name:

```
@Autowired
private Service service;

System.out.println(service.getClass().getName());
```

However with Spring beans the spring container has usually proxied them so it's not always helpful, in the case above the class is a Spring class called:

```
hello.HelloServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad2e225d
```

I suspect you should look at Jackson serializers which should handle all this, see [Java - Jackson Annotations to handle no suitable constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852335/java-jackson-annotations-to-handle-no-suitable-constructor/38853596#38853596)